# Invert feature scaling

Tags: r, feature-scaling

In my `dataset` I have a binary `Target` (0 or 1) variable, and 8 features: `nchar`, `rtc`, `Tmean`, `week_day`, `hour`, `ntags`, `nlinks` and `nex`. `week_day` is a factor while the others are numeric. I built a decision tree classifier, but my question concerns the feature scaling:

```
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(dataset$Target, SplitRatio = 0.75)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)
# Feature Scaling
training_set[-c(2,4)] = scale(training_set[-c(2,4)])
test_set[-c(2,4)] = scale(test_set[-c(2,4)])
```

The model returns that `Tmean=-0.057` and `ntags=2` are two splitting points. How can I recover the original value of these two features, that is, that assumed by the variables before the rescaling operation performed by `scale()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data were scaled with `scale`, the following function `unscale` might be of help solving the question.
The original vector and the unscaled one are `all.equal` but not `identical`, due to floating-point precision.

```
unscale <- function(x){
  xbar <- attr(x, "scaled:center")
  se <- attr(x, "scaled:scale")
  if(is.null(xbar) & is.null(se)){
    x
  } else {
    y <- t(se * t(x) + xbar)
    attr(y, "scaled:center") <- NULL
    attr(y, "scaled:scale") <- NULL
    y
  }
}

set.seed(2020)
A <- matrix(rnorm(120, sd = 16), ncol = 5)
s <- scale(A)
identical(A, unscale(s))  #FALSE

zeros <- as.vector(A - unscale(s))
all.equal(zeros, rep(0, 120))  
#[1] TRUE
```

The function also works with data.frames but the class of its output is `"matrix"`, not the original `"data.frame"`. This is the result of `scale`'s output.

```
B <- as.data.frame(matrix(A, ncol = 5))
s2 <- scale(B)
B2 <- as.data.frame(unscale(s2))
all.equal(B, B2)
#[1] TRUE
```

But the right way of scaling/unscaling an object with a `dim` attribute, such as a data.frame, is vector by vector. This can be done with a `lapply` loop, for instance.

```
s3 <- B
s3[] <- lapply(B, scale)

B3 <- s3
B3[] <- lapply(s3, unscale)
all(B - B3 < .Machine$double.eps^0.5)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! But it seems that the function hasn't affected my dataframe. The values have not changed.

Comment: @Mark Have you assigned the result back to the df?

Comment: Yes, `training_set` and `test_set` are dataframe. However, the problem could be that `attr(training_set, "scaled:center")` returns `NULL`. I can't explain why.

Comment: @Mark In the code you've posted, `training_set` is not scaled. So, there is no reason for the `"scaled:*"` attributes to be set.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to include the feature scaling part.